# Unknown Date format ( 7 digits )

Tags: javascript, php, date, date-format

Hi I'm building some custom function for my [Easy PHP Calendar](http://easyphpcalendar.com/)
Most of the source code is encoded so i use the database directly to 
Get the needed events rows.

My problem is translating the date format they use ( only date without time ) 
its stored as a 7 digit number.

for example if I add an event on **02/04/2014** it is saved as **2456693**
(time is saved in another column)

I tried to change the calendar settings to check if those values are affected

- changed date format - no change.
- changed calendar first and last year - no change.
- changed timezone - no change.

Do you have any Idea which date-format they use - (no answer from them)?

Comment: what is the value stored if you have the date `2014-Jan-01` and again for `2014-Dec-31`?

Comment: or just store 1. Jan 0000 and see if that work'S - otheriwse, we know at least that there is an offset and the format isn't able to store all dates.

Comment: 2014-Dec-31 - > 2457023 , 2014-Jan-01 -> 2456659

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Julian day number](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), or the number of days since 1 January 4713 BC.

Comment: You even have it confirmed in their Knowledge Base - http://www.easyphpcalendar.com/support/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=28

Comment: Was just gonna say that :-) PHP offers `GregorianToJD` and `JDToGregorian` to convert between Julian and our “normal” Gregorian calendar,

Comment: @ShlomiHassid no worries!